# Bad Superblock when mounting LVM SSD

Tags: mount, fedora, dd, superblock

I made a complete copy of my Fedora boot ssd using dd however the new drive does not boot correctly and is not mountable when connected via usb enclosure on a different machine. I get a bad superblock error when trying to mount /dev/fedora/home and /dev/fedora/root.

When i try to boot from it directly it starts to boot fedora but then drops to the emergency shell.

I have tried running fsck on the two ext4 volumes but this did not seem to help.

I also made a second copy to another known good ssd and got the same results.

Some relevant console output is pasted below.

Apologies if this has been answered before. I tried the advice in a few other posts on this forum with no luck.

```
sdb                         8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sdb1                      8:17   0   200M  0 part
├─sdb2                      8:18   0     1G  0 part
└─sdb3                      8:19   0 110.6G  0 part
  ├─fedora-swap           253:1    0   5.9G  0 lvm
  ├─fedora-home           253:2    0  54.7G  0 lvm
  └─fedora-root           253:3    0    50G  0 lvm

  matthew@radio:~$ sudo vgchange -ay fedora
  3 logical volume(s) in volume group "fedora" now active

  LV        VG        Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home      fedora    -wi-a----- 54.72g
  root      fedora    -wi-a----- 50.00g
  swap      fedora    -wi-a----- <5.87g

matthew@radio:~$ sudo mount /dev/fedora/home /mnt/fedora/home
mount: /mnt/fedora/home: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/fedora-home, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Comment: Try the advice from [this post](https://community.hpe.com/t5/LVM-and-VxVM/mounting-lvm-disk-that-was-from-another-system-and-NOT-exported/td-p/2455275) that uses vgimport.